# how to generate PX files from CSV files

Tags: r, csv, export

Q1.I have a CSV  file that I want to generate a PX file from using R.
Can you help me about how can I do that in R please?

Q2. I understand that PX file format do not accept character variables .what should I do if I want to create a PX file from CSV file that contains a character variable which I want to sort my data using this character variable 
when the PX is created ?

thanks guys,

Salem

Comment: Dear SALEM, welcome SE. Could you elaborate your question more, as not many people aware about CountrySTAT and PC-Axis. Some examples or code would be of help. Also you can have a look at `pxR` which allows to save PX-files.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `data.frame` into PX-format with `pxR` package. PX-format requirement is that the data should be presented in "narrow" format - only one numeric value for different combinations of factors. Moreover there should be at least three factor column.

The code below is addresing above-mentioned issues. `faithful` dataset was used an example.

```
library(pxR)
data(faithful)

library(reshape2)
# you should have at least three factor columns and one value column
# so, artificially adding id as factor to further identify eruptions
# and waiting time
faithful$id <- factor(seq.int(nrow(faithful)))

# then transform wide format data.frame (with 3 columns) into
# narrow format data.frame
df <- melt(faithful)

# then to meet PX format requirement
# add the copy of column variable
# which identify either it "eruption" or "waiting"
df$x <- df$variable

# converse to PX format
my_px <- as.px(df)

# save PX-file
write.px(my_px, "my_px.px")
```

Comment: Dear Artem,Thanks for you reply, please if you can use famous dataset in R as a real example for the code you gave then I will be very thankful, sorry I am just new to this. and how to save the new px file please?

Comment: Hi SALEM, could you send a link to this dataset. (Maybe `faithful`?)

Comment: Hi Artem, this is the link for faithful dataset: https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/rdataset/source/tree/master/csv/datasets/faithful.csv    . I am waiting your answer please?  Thanks for cooperating, Salem.

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for your answer.